# My php script is killed automatically by the OS (DEBIAN)

Tags: php, debian, system-administration

I have a php script that is killed after 10 minutes by the OS (debian)

I don't want it to be killed

Someone told me that my server maybe has a task monitor that kills long-running processes as a safeguard against lockups.

I don't know how to access to the task monitor and how to disable it

Comment: Call your server/web host company and ask them.

Comment: Tell us what error you get atleast!!

Answer (score 0):

What Apache error log says?

If you have error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of ...
```

then you have to turn off limit for PHP script execution time, which can be set like this:

```
set_time_limit(0); // limit in seconds, 0 for unlimited

while (1)// test loop
{
    $a = 0; 
}
```

You may set this an option in `php.ini` file, its `max_execution_time`.