# TCL script killed automatically by Debian after a while

Tags: linux, debian, tcl, kill

I have a TCL script that executes a groundwater model on a Debian machine, then runs a bunch of post-processing operations.

After a while (can't say exactly how long, probably several hours) the TCL script stops unexpectedly (including the execution of the groundwater model, if it is mid-run). The only feedback I get is simply a text on the console saying "Killed". I don't know by who or by what.

I found a couple of posts referring to a fix in php, e.g.:
[My php script is killed automatically by the OS (DEBIAN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146687/my-php-script-is-killed-automatically-by-the-os-debian)

but I don't know how to solve it for a TCL script.

Comment: Is this your machine?  If it's someone else's they may be running a monitor that kills long running processes  Otherwise you might be hitting some limit (maybe ulimits)

Comment: os won't kill your program if it's running good. you should debug your software instead. put sufficient log to help you reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks people. The code itself runs fine - I basically run multiple realizations of the same model, and post-process the results after each run. After two or so iterations of run/process, the Killed message appears and everything is dropped. I know the codes are fine, because if I start at a later model iteration, it runs without a problem (in other words, neither the model nor the post-process code are crashing)

Comment: I tend to agree with Kevin that it is an OS definition issue. I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with Linux / Unix "guts". Where would I find such a setting?

Comment: My guess is that you're hitting the [Linux Out of Memory process killer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-oom-killer-decides-which-process-to-kill-first).

Comment: msw - good catch. I looked at the "error.log" file that is in the Apache2 folder, and I see: "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of [xxx] bytes exhausted (tried to allocated XXX bytes) in..." followed by the name of the relevant PHP file. The way things are set up, there is a PHP code that executes the TCL code, which runs the groundwater model. I'll have to figure out how to free resources and variables after they are no longer needed.               Thanks again.